# Does Oracle Database have open issue list?

Tags: oracle

I am carrying out some study of bugs in Databases, so I have to dig into those bugs reported by the users of databases. As we know, MySQL, MariaDB, PostgreSQL have ether open bug repository or open mailing list to track. HOWEVER, Oracle DB does not have such kind of thing.

Is that right ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle is not open-source, so no, they don't have a public bug tracker. If you have a support contract, you can see some bugs on Oracle Support, fixed and some not, but there are also unpublished bugs, not visible to the public.